# What is foreignKey and inverseForeignKey in @JoinTable annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am having a project where I found, a schema something like this

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data

@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@IdClass(QuarantinePolicyIdentity.class)
@Entity(name = PolicyServiceConstants.QUARANTINE_POLICY_TABLE)
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = PolicyServiceConstants.QUARANTINE_POLICY_UNIQUE_NAME_CONSTRAINT,
        columnNames = {"customerUuid", "name"}),
        indexes = {@Index(name = PolicyServiceConstants.QUARANTINE_POLICY_UNIQUE_INDEX,
                columnList = "orderNo",
                unique = false)
        })
public class QuarantinePolicyEntity {

    @Id
    private String quarantinePolicyId;

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String customerUuid;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = PolicyServiceConstants.QUARANTINE_POLICY_OUTBOUND_RULE_TABLE,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = PolicyServiceConstants.FOREIGN_KEY_QUARANTINE_POLICY_QPOR),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = PolicyServiceConstants.FOREIGN_KEY_QUARANTINE_POLICY_ORQP))
    private Set<RuleEntity> outboundRules;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = PolicyServiceConstants.QUARANTINE_POLICY_INBOUND_RULE_TABLE,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = PolicyServiceConstants.FOREIGN_KEY_QUARANTINE_POLICY_QPIR),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = PolicyServiceConstants.FOREIGN_KEY_QUARANTINE_POLICY_IRQP))
    private Set<RuleEntity> inboundRules;

    private String createdBy;

    private Date createdDate;

    private String lastModifiedBy;

    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof QuarantinePolicyEntity)) return false;
        QuarantinePolicyEntity that = (QuarantinePolicyEntity) o;
        return com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(getQuarantinePolicyId(), that.getQuarantinePolicyId()) &&
                com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(getCustomerUuid(), that.getCustomerUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), quarantinePolicyId, customerUuid);
    }

}
```

- I am not able to understand what is `foreignKey` and `inverseForeignKey` in `@JoinTable`.
- Secondly, do we have to mention the FK, RuleEntity table, as how does it know which FK to take?

Thanks.

Comment: which jpa provider you are using ?

Comment: Hibernate, using Oracle db

Answer (score 1):

### What does the JPA documentation say?

If you visit the `JoinTable` annotation doc you will find

> **`foreignKey`** (Optional) Used to specify or control the generation of a foreign key constraint for the columns corresponding to the
> `joinColumns` element  *when table generation is in effect*.
>
> **`inverseForeignKey`** (Optional) Used to specify or control the generation of a foreign key constraint for the columns corresponding
> to the `inverseJoinColumns` element *when table generation is in effect*.

### Do you really need these?

So you can see these two attributes are defining the foreign key contraint creation during schema generation. Not the foreign key itself. The foreign keys are defined with the `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns` attribute.

Now if you dont put those `foreignKey` and `inverseForeignKey`, then the default value is `ConstraintMode.PROVIDER_DEFAULT` that means the database you are using (Oracle here) will decide the name of the foreign key constraint.

So you dont really need to explicitly provide the `foreignKey` and `inverseForeignKey` unless you want. These are optional attribute.

### More ways to improve the association

- I dont know wheather its a working code or not. But actually the `OneToMany` association is not properly defined here. There is no `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns` association (so nothing is telling which column to map). The association should be defined this way

  ```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "join_table_name",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "column_a"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "column_b"),
               foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "name_of_the_constraint_for_column_a"),
               inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "name_of_the_constraint_for_column_b"))
    private Set<RuleEntity> outboundRules;
  ```
- Moreover you dont even need a **JoinTable** for a **OneToMany** association either. Simply a `JoinColumn` should do the job. Think about the association, if its unidirectional or bi directional or which side is the owning side of the relationship. You will find handful of options to optimize your association.

More read:

- [JPA Documentation on JoinTable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html#foreignKey())
- [Efficient ways to map OneToMany associations](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)